# Django Model won't update after saving it once

Tags: django, django-views

I have been stuck on this for 5 hours and can't solve it! I trimmed out some of the fat.
Does anyone see why my **design saves at first**, but it wont update with the files primary key?

If I place: `design.files_id = 12` before the first `design.save()`, it will save that integer. But how do I get this form to re-save? I've even tried to reselect the model with the new primary key `design = store_models.Design.objects.get(pk = design.pk)` and no luck.

```
    form = SubmitDesignForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():

        design = form.save(commit = False)
        design.user = request.user
        design.save()
        form.save_m2m()

        # Files
        posted_files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        if posted_files:

            files = Files()
            files.save()
            print files.pk # Returns a Intenger

            design.files_id = files.pk
            design.save()
            # Always leaves the thing
```

*Note: The code is successfully creating data in the DB for Files and uploading them -- I just cant get the primary key to reference.*

Comment: Why don't you move `design.save()` and `form.save_m2m()` at the end (after the if block)?

Comment: Because it will say: "<Design: h >" needs to have a value for field "design" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How frustrating this was.. Here's what I did wrong:

**Design models.py**

```
def save(self):
    if self.download_price is None:
        self.download_price = '0.00'
        super(Design, self).save()
```

Super wasn't getting called when saving an item WITH a download price, so this fixed it:

```
def save(self):
    if self.download_price is None:
        self.download_price = '0.00'

    super(Design, self).save()
```

Sorry I forgot to include this, I didn't even realize it at all until I sat on the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to set the FK object, rather than the key? I don't think you insert the FK directly.
Try something like this (not 100% on the syntax):

```
design.files = Files.objects.get(pk=files.pk)
design.save()
```

Something like that. 
Of course, you already have a variable called `files` so you wouldn't need to do the get.
You should be able to try it from the command line.